# Logging approach in Azure WebApp for Containers

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, containers, azure-web-app-service

I am designing an ASP.NET Core application to run as WebApp for Container.I am logging application exceptions in a text file. I am also using Application Insight package to capture telemetry. I have hosted the application in WebAapp for Container.

Where can I find and download the log text files?

Also, is the above mentioned approach is right for logging when the application is designed as WebApp for Container? If not then what would the right approach be?

Also, Application Insight mostly generate telemetry information. Can I integrate the text logs for my application with Application Insight for better application log analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am designing an ASP.NET Core application to run as WebApp for Container.I am logging application exceptions in a text file. I am also using Application Insight package to capture telemetry. I have hosted the application in WebAapp for Container.

I would log the exceptions to Application Insights (AI) as well. Unhandled exceptions will already end up in AI if you use the SDK. Also, you can track them manually:

```cs
try
{
    ....
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
}
```

> Also, Application Insight mostly generate telemetry information. Can I integrate the text logs for my application with Application Insight for better application log analytics?

Yes you can. Using the AI SDK there are several types of telemetry you can send, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#api-summary). For text logging I suggest using `TrackTrace`:

`telemetry.trackTrace("a message", SeverityLevel.Information);`

You could also use `TrackEvent` but it can store less data ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/695))

Now, instead of using `TrackTrace` for custom text logging you could also use the `ILogger` interface and do logging like [the usual .net core way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It has [support for AI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#azure-application-insights) and will write logs to AI as traces as well.

In all scenario's, do mind that [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) may result in not all telemetry being available in AI, so either turn it off or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write the application exceptions to files explicitly. All the exceptions will be logged when you integrate Application Insights with your application. You can view the exceptions in the **Failures** blade of AI instance

### Update1:

In the Below screenshot, you can view the Top 3 Exception types. And, the **500** response code also shows you the exceptions. All that without much code. You can view my article [here](https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2020/07/11/6-steps-to-integrate-application-insights-with-net-core-application-hosted-in-azure-app-service/) for a step-by-step detailed instructions on how to integrate Application Insights to an asp.net core app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Failures blade will show HTTP call failures only. I believe we should  always log application error exceptions in a log file. How can I view or download  that log if the application is hosted as Webapp for Container?  Can we integrate that log with Application Insight?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a middleware for logging request and response on Application Insight. you can create a service for logging to log the exception in application Insight too.

### Middleware

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private static readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
    private readonly string appName;
    private readonly bool loggingEnabled;

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _next = next;
        configuration = config;
        _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
        telemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey =  configuration.GetValue<string>("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey");
        telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        appName = configuration.GetValue<string>("AppName");
        loggingEnabled = configuration.GetValue<bool>("Logging:LogRequestResponse"); 
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if(loggingEnabled)
        {
            await LogRequest(httpContext);
            await LogResponse(httpContext);
        }
    }

    private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();

        await using var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
        await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);

        string correlationId = context.Request.Headers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(h => h.ToLower() == "correlationid");
        if (correlationId == null) correlationId = string.Empty;
        if (context.Request.Path != "/")
        {
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent($"{appName}-RequestMiddleware", new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "AppName", appName },
                { "CorrelationId" , correlationId },
                { "Method" , context.Request.Method },
                { "Scheme", context.Request.Scheme},
                { "Host", context.Request.Host.Value },
                { "Path", context.Request.Path },
                { "QueryString", context.Request.QueryString.Value },
                { "Request Body", ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream) }

            });
        }
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }

    private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
    {
        const int readChunkBufferLength = 4096;

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        var readChunk = new char[readChunkBufferLength];
        int readChunkLength;

        do
        {
            readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk,
                                               0,
                                               readChunkBufferLength);
            textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
        } while (readChunkLength > 0);

        return textWriter.ToString();
    }

    private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        await using var responseBody = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream();
        context.Response.Body = responseBody;

        await _next(context);

        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var text = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        if (context.Request.Path != "/")
        {
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent($"{appName}-ResponseMiddleware", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"Scheme", context.Request.Scheme},
                { "AppName", appName },
                {"Host", context.Request.Host.Value},
                {"Path" , context.Request.Path},
                {"QueryString", context.Request.QueryString.Value},
                {"Response Body" , text}
                });
        }
       await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
    }
}


// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class LoggingMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggingMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
    }
}
```